# How to add link or image as a response in dialog flow for web demo

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-developer-tools

I am trying to create a chat bot for my website and in the response I need to add a link or image for web demo, but it seems to be available only in another platforms like face-book or slack and not for web.
Please help me to how to add an link/image response for web?

Comment: Which tool are you using to create this web? It will be different depending on the coding.. :)

Comment: In the console of dialog-flow I am trying to add replies under Intents.

Comment: Oh, then could you maybe response a link and with javascript take the response an print an image tag with this link as the source?

Answer (score 3):

Dialogflow's "web demo" integration doesn't currently support links or images in responses.

Comment: So what is the use of Dialogflow then? I thought it was supposed to be a tool to create chatbots, and the majority of chatbots are on websites.